# Can't get on-download-complete to work with aria2

Tags: shell, aria2

I've tried using the option at command line, used it in the aria2.conf file as well. But it just doesn't execute the on-download-complete shell file when it completes a torrent download. I ran aria2c as root, created the shell script as root, but didn't work. I created a new user and ran aria2c with that user and created a shell script with that too, that didn't work. Is there a log I can check on why aria2c doesn't run my shell script after the download completes?

The commandline options:

```
aria2c --torrent=1.torrent  --on-download-complete=/home/myself/run.sh
```

Any suggestions? I've tried this on a CentOS 5.5 and Ubuntu 11.04. If there's no other solution possible, is there any other command line torrent client for linux that can post parameters to a shell script (preferably php file) after the download completes?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Update. I couldn't get the on-download-complete option to work with aria2 no matter what I tried. So I moved on to rtorrent. It's quite nifty, has quite a lot of configuration options, and thankfully executes a shell script/php script when the download completes. For someone who's looking for just a torrent client that calls a shell script when a download completes, give rtorrent a try.

Comment: man just use `--on-bt-download-complete` you don't have to switch to rtorrent

Answer (score 3):

Try `--on-bt-download-complete`

According to the man: "this option set the command to be executed after download completed but before seeding"

the command you were using:

`--on-download-complete`

is run after seeding is also complete